# Family of Analytic Functions on the Unit Disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is the question:

Let $f_{t}(z)$ be a family of entire functions depending analytically on $t \in \Delta$. Suppose that $f_{t}(z)$ is non-vanishing on $S^{1}$ for all $t$. Prove that for each $k \geq 0$

$N_{k}(t)= \sum_{\left|z\right| <1, f_{t}(z)=0}z^{k}$

is an analytic function of $t$. (the zeros of $f_{t}(z)$ are taken with multiplicity).

I'm not quite sure where to begin with this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Dumb question: What does it mean for a family of functions to depend analytically on $t$? Does it just mean that $t\mapsto f_t(z)$ is analytic for each point $z$?

Comment: That's what I've been taking it to mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding Robert Israel's response, let

$$h(t) = \int_{|z| = 1} z^k \dfrac{f'_t(z)}{f_t(z)} dz$$

Think about what $h$ must be equal to.

Comment: Hmm might I have a little more? I think I'm headed in the right direction, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: By the residue theorem, $ h (t) $ is equal to the sum of the residues of the integrand inside of the unit disk. What are the residues? How are they related to $ f_t $?

Comment: @user3462 Let $c$ be a zero of a holomorphic function $g(z)$. The function $g'(z)/g(z)$, has a pole of order 1 at $c$ with residue 1. Therefore, the residue of $z^k g'(z)/g(z)$ at $c$ is precisely $c^k$.

Comment: Right, so then we consider our function $N_{k}(t)$ which is equal to the sum of the $z^{k}$ at points within the unit disk where $f_{t}(z)$ vanishes (i.e. at zeroes). Thus at each $t$ for which $f_{t}(z)$ vanishes there is a polynomial term with exponent $k$ contributing to the sum (namely our $h(t)$). Hence, $N_{k}(t)$ is the sum of polynomials, which are necessarily analytic, depending on $t \geq 0$ in the unit disk. Then we can conclude that $N_{k}(t)$ is an analytic function depending on $t$.

Comment: @user3462 I think you are making this more complicated than it is. $ h (t) = N_k (t) $, and $ h $ is analytic.

Comment: Haha yes, or that. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: what is the residue of $z^k f'(z)/f(z)$ at a zero of $f$?